# Puppet file type with Regex

Tags: windows, file, module, puppet, puppet-enterprise

I need to ensure that file exist inside all sub-directories of specific directory.
for example:

Ensure that the `c:\myFile.txt` file and his contect exist at:

```
c:\path\to\folder\*\myFile.txt
```

how is it possible to do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with puppet DSL.

You need to create a custom script that does that for you on windows and execute that.